# Intersection over union for rectangles with different orientation

Tags: swift, math, computer-vision, geometry, computational-geometry

I need to implement an algorithm in swift to find the intersection over union (`IoU`) between two rectangles with different orientations in 2-dimensional space. I could not find any tutorials or sample codes to teach how to implement such an algorithm.

Could someone provide relevant resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [O'Rourke algorithm](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Spring16/ORourke82.pdf) for calculation of intersection of two convex polygons.
C and Java code is availaible on the page for book "[Computational Geometry in C](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/books/compgeom.html)"

[image]

Algorithm traverses edges of polygons until it finds intersection (using 
orientation test). After intersection it chooses "the most inner" edge from two possible next ones to build intersection core polygon (always convex).

When you have ordered list of vertices, you can calculate polygon area with [shoelace formula](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/area-of-a-polygon-with-given-n-ordered-vertices/).

To get area of union, we can calculate (thanks to Yves Daoust for hint)

```
Area(Union) = Area(P) + Area(Q) - Area(Intersection)
```

Comment: There is non need to compute the union, Area(Union) + Area(Intersection) = Area(P) + Area(Q).

Comment: @Yves Daoust Thanks, missed this simple fact

Comment: I'm looking at the file `ConvConv.java` whose comment says "used for computing intersection of two convex polygons". However, the public function only outputs a boolean value. I might be missing something. Could you explain how to use this code to actually get the area?

Comment: I've added link to shoelace formula to get area

Comment: ConvConv.java contains field `inters` - intersection polygon vertex list

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to the very good solution of MBo/O'Rourke, you can use a sweep line approach.

For convenience, assume that one of the polygons is axis aligned. Then there are two "events" when the line hits the top and bottom sides of the aligned rectangle and four events when the line hits the vertices of the other (depending on the orientation, there are 8 possible permutations of the vertices).

The intersection of the rectangles occurs inside the vertical ranges defined by these events (you perform a merge of the two event sets) and there are up two six intersections to be computed between the oblique sides and the horizontals. For every event line, it is an easy matter to determine the X intervals spanned by both rectangles, and find their intersection or union. And the areas between two event lines are trapezoids.

[image]

To cope with rectangles in general position, you can

- rotate both polygons to align one of them,
- work with a counter-rotated coordinate system,
- perform the sweep with an horizontal line anyway without moving the polygons; but then there are 8 events instead of 6 and up to 8 intersection computations.